# Как выводить в форме не код, а наименование объекта? 1с

Tags: 1с

Есть форма "Данные организации", в ней есть поле "Генеральный директор", тип ссылочный. В отдельном справочнике вводятся сотрудники, и из него выбирается директор в отдельной форме. Как сделать так, чтобы в поле отражалось наименование "Семенов В.П.", а не его код 000000002? Спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой тип, в свойствах, у реквизита "Генеральный директор"? И в Справочнике Сотрудники, основное представление в виде кода или в виде наименования?

Comment: Спасибо! Разобралась, у генерального директора основное представление было в виде кода, поменяла

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего основное представление стоит в виде кода, нужно переставить в виде наименования

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]